# Is there a way to connect jar to flowable admin

Tags: bpmn, flowable

I am using flowable on docker.

I have created a BPMN with a service task. so I need to connect a Java Delegate. But How could I execute that BPMN process using flowable-admin ( with java delegate or classpath ) which is running on docker?

Answer (score 0):

Flowable Admin does not contain the BPMN engine. It is an application that uses the REST API to get data from an application that has the REST APIs exposed.